# Is it OK to mount a partition to /home/

Tags: mount, permissions

My office system's HDD capacity was 500 GB, but the usable space was only around 100 GB. When I analysed disk I found that some of the space was used by `boot` and `swap` and the rest was used by an empty folder named `NewFolder` under the root directory. This folder was found to contain around 350 GB and was unusable(no read/write permission) for the user.

When I investigated more, It was found that the ownership of that folder was neither  root nor user (May be system admins did it by mistake during installation). So I changed the ownership to my user. And now I am able to access the entire space.

My question is, is it possible for me to mount this partition to my `home` directory? If possible how? If not possible, why?

**Edit**

Output of `df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5        92G   84G  3.8G  96% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            3.9G   12K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           786M  1.4M  785M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.9G   17M  3.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   76K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda6       922M  292M  567M  35% /boot
/dev/sda7       359G   67M  341G   1% /NewFolder
```

output of `cat /etc/fstab`

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=aede36a3-fb06-4fe0-969d-011f063ba568 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /NewFolder was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=efd23971-f61a-41f3-bd28-bbdf76c74673 /NewFolder         ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=d93f32a4-f5a2-4f3c-a243-6d20bad200ce /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=4ee0e7f2-03fa-489a-93bc-4152c69a1c26 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: What contents have that folder?

Comment: Please post the outpt of `df -h`

Comment: @Helio The folder is empty.

Comment: Can you post the output of `cat /etc/fstab`?

Comment: Now I see `df -h`.  NewFolder is a mount of `/dev/sda7` (a partition of 359GB)

Comment: @Helio Yes. I just noticed it now.  Would that make any problem?

Comment: @Stunts added `df -h` output. :)

Comment: Unclear, what do you mean? Mount as `/home` folder, in the `/home` folder, eg. `/home/NewFolder/` or into your home folder, eg `/home/<your_username>/NewFolder`?

Comment: @A.B into/in the home folder shall do. Both are Ok :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, it's possible

*Replace `<your_user_name>` with your user name and `NewFolder` with a name of your choice.*

---

Create a new mount point, eg:

```
mkdir ~/NewFolder
```

and mount

```
sudo mount /dev/sda7 $HOME/NewFolder
```

If it works then change the entry in your `fstab`:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

from this

```
UUID=efd23971-f61a-41f3-bd28-bbdf76c74673 /NewFolder         ext4    defaults        0       2
```

to this

```
UUID=efd23971-f61a-41f3-bd28-bbdf76c74673 /home/<your_user_name>/NewFolder            ext4    defaults        0       2
```

You can check the UUID with this command

```
sudo blkid /dev/sda7
```

Sample output:

```
/dev/sda7: UUID="d94f4097-91aa-4e96-89b2-7877065d0650" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="00096da5-01"
```

Comment: Do I need to use a live CD to do this?

Comment: Definitely not.

Comment: I see a slight difference in UUIDs when u edit the `fstab` entry. Could you please explain a bit on that?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Good that you have checked it.

Comment: The output of this command is always the right choice: `sudo blkid /dev/sda7`

Comment: Ok. I checked the command and compared the UUID with the one in `fstab`. It matches. I will check this and come back to you :)

Answer (score 2):

The home folder is supposed to hold your user folder. When you mount a partition to `/Home` the first thing that is created on that partition is the user's directory. You can mount any partition to `/home` and use.

If you value the data in that folder You could create a soft Link to that folder to any new folder  under your `/home` and call it whatever you like.

So if you did this:

```
sudo ln -s /NewFolder /home/NewFolder
```

This will create a symbolic Link to `/NewFolder` under `/home` and if you click on `/home/NewFolder` it will open the `/NewFolder` for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it:

First - I'd create a new filesystem on your partition:

Start by unmountig your partiton:

`sudo umount /dev/sda7`

Then, create the new filesystem:

`sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda7` **WARNING:** this will erase all contents of `/dev/sda7` partition.

Then, I'd temporarily mount it somewhere;

`sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt`

Then, I'd copy the contents of my home dir into the new partition:

`sudo rsync -avP /home/ /mnt/` (using rsync will maintain permissions)

Unmount the partition:

`sudo umount /dev/sda7`

edit `/etc/fstab` to mount your new partition on `/home` by changing the line:

`UUID=efd23971-f61a-41f3-bd28-bbdf76c74673 /NewFolder         ext4    defaults        0       2`

to:

`UUID=efd23971-f61a-41f3-bd28-bbdf76c74673 /home         ext4    defaults        0       2`

If you wish, you may now erase the contents of your old 'home'

`sudo rm -rf /home/*` **WARNING:** This is a destructive command, make sure your data is safe in the new partiton before you issue it!

Reboot and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

You can mount the 359GB partition in `/home` instead of `/NewFolder`

1. Boot from a live CD/USB
2. Mount /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda7
3. Run `sudo mv /mountpoint/to/dev/sda5/home/* /mountpoint/to/dev/sda7`
4. Edit `/etc/fstab`
5. On the line that mounts `/NewFolder`, replace `/NewFolder` by `/home`

---

Original line:

```
UUID=efd23971-f61a-41f3-bd28-bbdf76c74673 /NewFolder         ext4    defaults        0       2
```

Edited line:

```
UUID=efd23971-f61a-41f3-bd28-bbdf76c74673 /home         ext4    defaults        0       2
```

---

**Note:** This will store the home folder of all the users (except root) on the 359GB volume.

Comment: I hope this will also work. But I accept @A.B 's answer because it doesn't require the use of a live Cd. Thanks anyway :)